# Bash [[ test =~ regex ]] vs perl command result

Tags: bash, regex, bash-scripting, perl

Is the bash operator `=~` equivalent to a `perl` invocation?

```
filename="test-33.csv"
regex="([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv)"
```

With bash test:

```bash
if [[ "$filename" =~ $regex ]]; then echo "it matches"; else echo "doesn't match"; fi
# doesn't match

if [[ "$filename" =~ ([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv) ]]; then echo "matches"; else echo "doesn't match"; fi
# doesn't match
```

With `perl`:

```bash
result="$(perl -e "if ('$filename' =~ /$regex/) { exit 0;} else { exit 1;} ")"
if [[ result ]]; then echo "it matches"; else echo "doesn't match"; fi
# it matches
```

Is there anything I am missing for the bash `=~` operator? Does this have something to do with the greedy vs non-greedy iterator (`[^.]+`)?

Comment: See the Unix & Linux question ["Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several different types of Regular Expression, each one adding more operators (and therefore requiring more characters to be escaped if they are to be considered literals).

The `=~` operator is described in the documentation (see `man bash` on your system or online) like this,

> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the same precedence as `==` and `!=`. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a **POSIX extended regular expression** and  matched  accordingly

An Extended Regular Expression (ERE) can be matched with `grep -E` (formerly `egrep`). Your example is a Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE), which is a superset of the ERE and will not work with `=~`. However, it can be trivially adapted by replacing `\d` with `[[:digit:]]`:

```
echo abc-123.csv | grep -E '([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv)'             # ERE fails
echo abc-123.csv | grep -P '([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv)'             # PCRE matches with GNU grep

echo abc-123.csv | grep -E '([^.]+)(-[[:digit:]]{1,5})(\.csv)'    # ERE matches modified expression
```

So, given that `grep -E` is equivalent to `=~` we can therefore write this,

```
if [[ "$filename" =~ ([^.]+)(-[[:digit:]]{1,5})(\.csv) ]]
then
    echo "matches"
else
    echo "doesn't match"
fi
```

Note that your ERE should probably be prefixed with `^` and suffixed with `$`, and the `[^.]+` adapted to `[^-.]+` to ensure that you can't match strings such as `abc-def-12345678-123.csv.txt`:

```
^[^-.]+-[[:digit:]]{1,5}\.csv$
```

If you're absolutely set on using a PCRE rather than an ERE you will have to use an external tool such as the GNU implementation of `grep` to perform the match. But this is less efficient, and the same advice about bounding applies here as is given above:

```
if echo "$filename" | grep -qP '([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv)'
then
    echo "matches"
else
    echo "doesn't match"
fi
```

The POSIX reference for basic REs (RE or BRE) and EREs is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html, and the reference for Perl REs (PCRE) is at https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html. Be warned that neither is the easiest of documentation to understand.

Finally, you ask,

> Does this have something to do with the greedy vs non-greedy iterator `([^.]+)`?

That isn't a greedy/non-greedy iterator. `[^.]+` is greedy and means "*one or more of anything except a dot (`.`)*". EREs do not have non-greedy operators. PCREs can define a non-greedy operator such as `*` or `+` by following it with `?`. For example contrast `a*` and `a*?`; the first will match as many `a` characters as possible and the second will match as few as possible.

The `( … )` bracket is a grouping, not a greediness indicator.

Comment: _"each one adding more operators (and therefore requiring more characters to be escaped"_ -- except that BRE has some characters that are special exactly when "escaped" by backslashes, mainly  `\{`/`\}` and `\(`/`\)` (but _not_ `\+`or `\|`).

Comment: @ilkkachu yes I know, but I'm trying to keep a complex subject as simple as I dare

Answer (score 4):

The operator `=~` in `Bash shell` is equivalent to `grep -E` GNU command. `Perl` regex are not recognized with it. You need to do something like :

```
~$ [ $(echo "$filename" | grep -Po "$regex") ] && echo "it matches" || echo "does not match"
it matches
```

to have an equivalent.

About `grep` options used :

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

With your original form this looks like :

```
if [[ $(echo "$filename" | grep -Po "$regex") ]]; then echo "it matches"; else echo "does not match"; fi
```

This works too :

```
if [ $(echo "$filename" | grep -Po "$regex") ]; then echo "it matches"; else echo "does not match"; fi
```

You have also the possibility to do :

```
yyy@xxx:~$ filename="test-33.csv"
yyy@xxx:~$ regex="([^.]+)(-\d{1,5})(\.csv)"
yyy@xxx:~$ result=$(echo "$filename" | grep -Po "$regex")
yyy@xxx:~$ if [[ $result ]]; then echo "it matches"; else echo "does not match"; fi
it matches
yyy@xxx:~$
```

Comment: Instead of the `[` testing non-empty output from grep (unquoted is bad), use `grep -q` -- `echo "$filename | grep -qP "$regex" && echo match || echo no match`

Comment: Would select this as the best answer. Could you please align your answer with the question... the form is `if [[ expression ]]; then ...; else ...; fi`

Comment: Thank you ! It's done

Comment: Thanks @hidigoudi . The other answer (edited) offers a more complete explanation. I like of yours that went straight to address the target result, though. Here some reference on the [bash if statements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306115) that explains the `PCRE` solution of the other answer. By the way, option `-q` (silent) gets to  bring the exit status code to the if condition.

Comment: No problem, I understand, thank you for the vote up !

Answer (score 0):

Bash has [extended glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) which get closer to regular expressions. Within `[[...]]` the `==` operator does glob-style pattern matching.

```bash
filename=test-33.csv
# one or more non-dots, a hyphen, a digit, optionally 4 more digits, the extension
pattern='+([^.])-[0-9]?([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9]).csv'
[[ $filename == $pattern ]] && echo Y || echo N
```

If you're using the regex to filter a list of filenames, use the glob pattern in a for loop instead.

```bash
shopt -s extglob
for file in $pattern; do
    # do something with the file.
    echo "$file"
done
```

Notes

- the `shopt` command: extended glob is automatically enabled within `[[...]]` but not otherwise.
- `$pattern` is specifically unquoted in these code snippets so that it gets handled as a pattern not a literal string.